# Propagation of error from statistical error

Tags: error-propagation

We have done the determination of protein abundance in two fractions (M and P) in one condition (SP).
We've done three biological replicas.
The data obtained are:
\begin{align*}
&\text{SP (condition)} &&\text{M (fraction) mean} &&&\text{M standard error} \\
&\text{SP (condition)} &&\text{P (fraction) mean} &&&\text{P standard error}
\end{align*}
The calculation we want to do is: Log (P/M) for SP condition.
How can I calculate the propagation of errors?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question better answered by a quick Google search, but since I have it on hand, check [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty). It shows that, in general, the propagated standard deviation in a function of multiple statistically independent variables is given by,
\begin{gather*}
\sigma_f \approx \sqrt{\sum_j \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} \right)^2 \sigma_{x_j}^2}
\end{gather*}
where $j$ runs over the various independent variables $\{ x_j\}$ that $f$ depends on.

While I cannot quite tell anything about your situation because your question is unclear and uses completely undefined acronyms, I am operating on the assumption that you have some function,
\begin{gather*}
f(P,M) \propto \ln \left( \frac{P}{M} \right)
\end{gather*}
The necessary derivatives are obtained with basic calculus,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial P} &= \frac{M}{P} \cdot \frac{1}{M} = \frac{1}{P} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial M} &= \frac{M}{P} \cdot -\frac{P}{M^2} = -\frac{1}{M} \\
\implies \sigma_f &\approx \sqrt{\left( \frac{1}{P} \right)^2 \sigma_P^2 + \left( -\frac{1}{M} \right)^2 \sigma_M^2 } = \sqrt{\frac{\sigma_P^2}{P^2} + \frac{\sigma_M^2}{M^2} }
\end{align*}
where in the last line $M$ and $P$ refer to the average values of the variables $M$ and $P$ that you measured in the lab and $\sigma_P$ and $\sigma_M$ refer to the standard deviations of their measurements. I may be completely wrong about your entire situation, but this approach is applicable to whatever equation you happen to need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply

the function is 

f (P,M)  log 10 (P/M)

where P and M are dependent variables

Comment: Ok, so the answer is almost identical to what I posted. Just swap out the derivative of natural log for the log base 10 and you’re good to go.

Comment: But P and M are dependent variables, so their correlation is needed in the slightly more complicated analysis.

Comment: Ahhh, if the variables are meaningfully correlated you should account for the covariance between them. But if it’s small this still works well.